# Unmet dependencies of "Bundle :: Expect" while loading module in CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I am loading a new module in CPAN, [`Net::Netconf`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aNetconf), but while installing this module its giving error that [`Bundle::Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bundle%3a%3aExpect) not found.

I have mentioned all the dependencies of this module in Makefile.PL, but `Bundle::Expect` is giving error, its saying this module not found.

Is there some other name for this module or I have to mention dependencies in some other file, so that I can be automatically installed by CPAN while installing my module?

Below is my Makefile.PL

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use 5.006;

WriteMakefile(
    NAME         => 'Net-Netconf',
    AUTHOR       => 'Juniper Networks, Inc',
    VERSION_FROM => 'Makefile.PL',
    PREREQ_PM =>
      { 'XML::LibXML' => '0', 'File::Which' => '0', 'Bundle::Expect' => '0', },
    ABSTRACT => 'netconf libraries for perl',
);
```

Comment: Add the contents of your Makefile to the question.  Comments are for commenting, not for adding information to the question.  Welcome to SO  :)

Comment: I think maybe you can't use a bundle file as a dependency; just list all the dependencies individually.

Comment: Afaik is this module out of date: http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Bundle-Expect